# Having objects trajctories and directions how to find where objects traverse same path?

Tags: searching

I have `N` objects that travel on some trajectories (unique for each object). At each agent curve point we can get object speed (direction). Having some distance creteria `d` how to find where more than one curve go in same direction cloze to each other with distance `<= d`?

alike having black object trajectory curves we find red curve that with some `d` follows most curves direction:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "same direction" is not well defined unless the curves are closed.
Say your curves are indeed closed, then the sign of the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the curves described by $g_i(t) = (x_i(t),y_i(t))$ can give you the "direction" of each of the curves. Now split the curves into clockwise and counter-clockwise groups, and find the closest points between curves in each group - i.e for each pair of oriented curves find $t_1^0$ and $t_2^0$ such that:
$$\frac{\partial\sqrt{\left(x_i(t_1)-x_j(t_2)\right)^2+\left(y_i(t_1)-y_j(t_2)\right)^2}}{\partial t_{1,2}}=0$$
Now check if:
$$\sqrt{\left(x_i(t_1^0)-x_j(t_2^0)\right)^2+\left(y_i(t_1^0)-y_j(t_2^0)\right)^2}<d$$
QED.

Comment: Curves are not closed at all, they are more like an array of trajectories that are representations of people walking thrue a public space...

Comment: @Kabumbus - as I said, in that case, there is no well defined meaning for "same direction". In any case, you can always close your curves outside your ROI.

Comment: A trajectory doesn't have to be closed for direction to be well defined, otherwise how would one define the directed line segment making up a vector, or a parabolic path that is oriented in space